# Filter that dumps HttpServletRequest & Response to files

Tags: java, servlets, logging

Im after something that watches all requests/responses and when triggered then writes several dump files such as

- request line url method etc

  GET url HTTP/1.0
- request headers with parameter k/v on a separate line

  a=b
  c=d
  e=f
- request post body, dump of the initial post data

  ashdashdiuhasidahs diasdad
- response status, on a single line

  200 OK
- response headers, each header appears on a separate line.

  a=b
  c=dddd
  e=fff
- response body, the written output as is.

  asjiasjdoiajdo iajdaoi djaoidsjaod

it should use a common unique prefix for the set of files that it dumps. This naming should be configurable.

Comment: You could just write one

Comment: Good Write one and help if anyone finds difficulty in writing such things.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Tomcat, you can use the RequestDumperValve. Enable it by opening the server.xml and uncommenting it out as instructed in there:

```
<!-- <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve"/> -->
```

It seems like it addresses some (if not all) of your requirements. For more information check this out (which also mentions RequestDumperFilter, but I have not used that before)

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/valve.html#Request_Dumper_Valve

Logs appear in the TOMCAT_HOME\logs\catalina file

*One last note though, I only used in Non-PRD environment, as it has performance impact as the comments in the server.xml will warn you...*

Comment: I just cheked the source, reading the parameters so they can be logged would screw up any multipart file upload, i think...

Comment: I forgot to mention that the valve also does not log the text or binary response or the if the request is a multipart request, nor does it dump the raw or cooked files that were uploaded.